# How to use skill versatility?

Tags: bard, racial-traits, proficiency, half-elf

I'm new to D&D and am making my first character. As she is a half-elf bard, I'm given 'skill versatility, which gives proficiency in any two skills. Where and when does this get added and how is it used?

Comment: What edition of D&D are you playing?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. What edition are you asking about? You can indicate this by editing the appropriate tag (e.g. [dnd-3.5e] or [dnd-5e]) into your post. Also, could you clarify what exactly you're confused by?

Comment: You're playing 5th edition D&D, but we need you to say that explicitly on this site.  You can do that by putting the [tag:dnd-5e] tag in your question, and/or by stating it *explicitly* in the question's body.  It may seem like people are being deliberately obtuse about that, but [that's our policy, unfortunately](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6867/what-to-do-when-an-edit-guesses-the-system-being-used-rather-than-waiting-for-th)

Comment: [related discussion of bards and proficiency and half elf here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/87691/22566)